# Is there a way to view the instances of UIView during a debug session in XCode?

Tags: xcode, ios6

I'm in the midst of debugging a hard to find issue with a view in XCode, and would love it if there was a way to inspect the current view hierarchy. In the past, my approach has been to remove all views in my app, and add each view back in, in order, until I could get the problem to re-appear. The aforementioned approach is time consuming, tedious, and begs for a more robust, repeatable solution.

So, I ask the group, is there a way to inspect the view hierarchy in XCode during a debug session? Is there a 3rd party utility that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debugger, you can type

```
> po [view recursiveDescription]
```

or if you want to use an NSLog statement

```
NSLog(@"%@", [view performSelector:@selector(recursiveDescription)]);
```

Apple mentions it in this document: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html

Otherwise, though, I have problems finding documentation for it so I don't know if it constitutes a "private API" or not.  In other words, you might not want to include it in code  you submit to the App Store.